# Find the instruction matching an opcode

Tags: tools, immunity-debugger

I have two bytes '`\x74\x06`' and I want a list of all instructions that start with this opcode.

What tools would you use for this? I am trying to do it with Immunity Debugger but so far no luck. The only solution I found is based on Example 3 from corelancoder's [cheatsheet](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2010/01/26/starting-to-write-immunity-debugger-pycommands-my-cheatsheet/). However this requires that there is a binary currently loaded in Immunity and that it contains an instruction starting with that opcode.

How can I quickly get a mapping (partial) opcode -> instruction?

Comment: `0x74` is always `jz`/`je` (they're synonymous). In Linux you can generate all byte sequences you're interested of, pipe them to some disassembler (I like [udcli](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/)) and `grep` the output for valid instructions, like this (to get all 2-byte x86-64 instructions that begin with `0f`): `bytes='0f'; bytes_wo_spaces=$(echo $bytes | tr -d ' '); for i in {0..255}; do printf "$bytes %x\n" $i | udcli -x -64; done | grep $bytes_wo_spaces | grep -v '\<invalid\>'`. This can be extended to longer instructions too (to some limit). It can probably be done in Windows console too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this with `radare2` program `rasm2`

```
rasm2 -a x86 -b 32 -d 7406

je 0x8
```

This has obviously already been established as `je` from the other answers.

But for arguments sake, say you wanted to decode all instructions starting with 0x74 for one additional byte, you could then run the above in a loop and try and find all valid instructions.  This example is for Linux or a Unix shell of some kind, I presume you could achieve the similar with `mingw` or Powershell:

```
for x in `seq 0 255`;do printf "74%02x " $x;rasm2 -a x86 -b 32 -d 74`printf "%02x" $x`;done
```

Produces:

```
7400 je 0x2
7401 je 0x3
7402 je 0x4
7403 je 0x5
```

(etc...)

Another example:

```
for x in `seq 0 255`;do printf "33%02x " $x;rasm2 -a x86 -b 32 -d 33`printf "%02x" $x`;done
```

gives

```
3300 xor eax, [eax]
3301 xor eax, [ecx]
3302 xor eax, [edx]
3303 xor eax, [ebx]
3304 disassemble error at offset 0
invalid
3305 disassemble error at offset 0
invalid
3306 xor eax, [esi]
```

(etc)

You could then write a script to grep out the errors and just show valid codes (or the opposite even if you wanted)

Answer (score 1):

If it's x86, and I'm quite sure it is, you should check [this](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html) link and [this](http://x86.renejeschke.de/) link.

Comment: Yes, as can be seen in yaspr's first link, only one x86 instruction starts with `0x74`: `JZ`/`JE` - http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x74

Comment: Thank you yaspr. The links are indeed very helpful. However I would appreciate a tool-based solution to avoid the dependencie to websites that might go offline without notice

Answer (score 0):

**windbg**
**0:000> .for ( r $t0 = 0; @$t0 < 0x8 ;r  $t0 = @$t0 +1 ) {eb eip 74 @$t0; u @eip l1 ; !opcodemap }**

```
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7400            je      calc!WinMain+0x7 (01001f58)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7400        01001f58
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7401            je      calc!WinMain+0x8 (01001f59)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7401        01001f59
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7402            je      calc!WinMain+0x9 (01001f5a)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7402        01001f5a
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7403            je      calc!WinMain+0xa (01001f5b)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7403        01001f5b
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7404            je      calc!WinMain+0xb (01001f5c)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7404        01001f5c
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7405            je      calc!WinMain+0xc (01001f5d)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7405        01001f5d
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7406            je      calc!WinMain+0xd (01001f5e)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7406        01001f5e
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 7407            je      calc!WinMain+0xe (01001f5f)

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
je  7407        01001f5f
```

trying another variation notice how disassemble with one constant byte one variable byte automatically pulls other bytes as needed

**0:000> .for ( r $t0 = 0; @$t0 < 0x8 ;r  $t0 = @$t0 +1 ) {eb eip ff @$t0; u @eip l1 ; !opcodemap }**

```
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff00            inc     dword ptr [eax]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff00        dword ptr [eax]    
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff01            inc     dword ptr [ecx]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff01        dword ptr [ecx]    
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff02            inc     dword ptr [edx]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff02        dword ptr [edx]    
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff03            inc     dword ptr [ebx]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff03        dword ptr [ebx]    
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff0406          inc     dword ptr [esi+eax]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff0406      dword ptr [esi+eax]
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff0506010081    inc     dword ptr ds:[81000106h]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff0506010081        dword pt
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff06            inc     dword ptr [esi]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff06        dword ptr [esi]    
calc!WinMain+0x5:
01001f56 ff07            inc     dword ptr [edi]

Instr   OpCode  Dest    Source
inc ff07        dword ptr [edi]
```